# Sanitize user-supplied URL for file_get_contents

Tags: php, proxy, file-get-contents

I want to use `file_get_contents` to implement a proxy so I can do cross domain AJAX requests.

Query string will be used to supply the URL to `file_get_contents`. Now the problem is people can muck around with the query string in order to read local files on the server. I don't want this. Can someone get me a function to sanitize the query string in order to accept only URLs and not local files, i.e.:

- `?url=http://google.com.au` - OK
- `?url=./passwords.txt` - Not OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$url = filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

or

```
if($_GET['url'] === filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    ... your stuff here ...
}
```

Comment: I ended up using :

FILTER_VALIDATE_URL and FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED

never heard of this function..quite handy thanks